# What are good ways to create a HTTP session with simultaneous requests?

Tags: python, http, session-state

I have a problem and can't solve it. Maybe I'm making it too hard or complex or I'm just going in the wrong direction and thinking of things that don't make sense. Below is a description of what happens. (Multiple tabs opened in a browser or a page that requests some other pages at the same time for example.)

I have a situation where 3 requests are received by the web application simultaneously and new user session has to be created. This session is used to store notification, XSRF token and login information when the user logs in. The application uses threads  to handle requests (CherryPy under Bottle.py).

The 3 threads (or processes in case or multiple application instances) start handling the 3 requests. They check the cookie, no session exists, and create a new unique token that is stored in a cookie and in Redis. This will all happen at the same time and they don't know if a session already has been created by another thread, because all 3 tokens are unique.

These unused sessions will expire eventually, but it's not neat. It means everytime a client simultaneously does N requests and a new session needs to be created, N-1 session are useless.

If there is a property that can be used to identify a client, like an IP address, it would be a lot easier, but an IP address is not safe to use in this case. This property can be used to atomically store a session in Redis and other requests would just pick up that session.

Answer (score 0):

If this is through a browser and is using cookies then this shouldn't be an issue at all. The cookie will, from what I can tell, the last session value that it is set to. If the client you are using does not use cookies then of course it will open a new session for each connection.